# how can I position costumes to the center in Scratch 3.0?

Tags: mit-scratch

The new version of Scratch was launched at the beginning of 2019. Unfortunately I could not find the button which was (in previous versions of Scratch) responsible for positioning things to the center . Of course you can do manually the positioning approximately, but you realize that it is not enough when you have some motions in the code, for example when bouncing back from edges. If anybody has an idea, how can I position new creatures exactly to the center, please share it.

Comment: A feature was recently added to Scratch that allows to do that: https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/386021/

Answer (score 1):

They removed the crosshairs tool in Scratch 3.0. However, the Scratch Team is trying to bring it back.

A way you can get *really close* to the center is doing the following (in vector mode): make a square around the edge of the canvas. Make the diagonals, and move the sprite where the diagonals meet. This isn't perfect, but is really good and is (probably) the best you can do.

---

#### Update:

There is a target tool in the center of the canvas, and that can be used to center, similar to the diagonal lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can't position costumes to the center in Scratch 3.0 anymore. The Scratch Team said they would add it back soon though.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to where the Scratch team mentioned this? Thanks!

Comment: Here: [Discussion Forum](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/336316/?page=1#post-3402302)

Comment: An easier way to do it is to select a shape (circle or rectangle), then hover your mouse over the center of the crosshair and hold down [SHIFT] and [ALT]. Then click and drag your mouse to adjust the size.

Answer (score 0):

There are dots on the edges of a selected shape, where you can resize it:

```
o------------0------------o
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
0            +            0
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
o------------0------------o
```

The center ones (marked in 0's) can serve as crosshairs. The little target circle in the center is where the center points should line up with. It is accurate, but may be tedious with a larger shape.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a small circle just above the center mark, move it to a top-level then draw your object and align with the circle. When you finish delete the circle. This is the best I can find so far until the positioning button comes back

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, the object center is back, so you can use it now!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plus with a circle in the middle of the editor tool and you just need to move the thing to the middle